# Zdog Box height won't grow

Tags: javascript, 3d, height

I'm making a 3D box with Zdog and I want to let the height of the box grow.
Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qzBMgp.

This is my code for the box:

```
let progressBox = new Zdog.Box({
  addTo: progress,
  width: 200,
  height: boxHeight,
  depth: 200,
  stroke: 1,
})
```

This is the code I use to increase the height of the box. If the box is shorter than `400`, the box will increase its height with `0.1`.

```
function animate() {

   if (boxHeight < 400) {
      moveUp = 'up';
    } else if (boxHeight > 400) {
      moveUp = 'false';
    }
      boxHeight += moveUp == 'up' ? 0.1 : 0;
 }
```

The problem is that the box stays at a height of `0` (the value I gave to boxHeight), but when I `console.log(boxHeight)` the `boxHeight` will grow.

Comment: First change your `else if` statement to `else` since it must end with the latter, and no need for the condition `boxHeight > 400`. You can optionally shorten it to: `(boxHeight < 400) ? moveUp = 'up' : moveUp = 'false';`

Comment: @Adrift I add a codepen!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me point out that you cannot change the value of a **constant** . On your code, the `boxHeight` is declared as `const`.

Second, you will need to use Zdog's [copy()](https://zzz.dog/api#anchor-copy) method. Here is your code modified accordingly.

```
Zdog.Anchor.prototype.renderGraphSvg = function (svg) {
  if (!svg) {
    throw new Error('svg is ' + svg + '. ' +
      'SVG required for render. Check .renderGraphSvg( svg ).');
  }
  this.flatGraph.forEach(function (item) {
    item.render(svg, Zdog.SvgRenderer);
  });
};

const TAU = Zdog.TAU;
const light = '#EAE2B7';
const yellow1 = '#FCBF49';
const orange1 = '#F77F00';
const red1 = '#d62828';
const purple1 = '#003049';
const white1 = '#ffffff';
const isSpinning = true;
var boxHeight = 0;


let progress = new Zdog.Illustration({
  element: '.progress',
  dragRotate: true,
  translate: {
    y: 25
  },
  rotate: {
    x: -0.4, y: 0.75
  }
});

let progressBox = new Zdog.Box({
  addTo: progress,
  width: 200,
  depth: 200,
  height: boxHeight,
  stroke: 1,
  color: purple1, // default face color
  leftFace: yellow1,
  rightFace: orange1,
  topFace: red1,
  bottomFace: light,
  translate: {
    x: 0,
    y: 300
  },
});



function animate() {

  if (boxHeight <= 400) {
    boxHeight++; // 1

    progressBox = progressBox.copy({
      height: boxHeight, // overwrite height
      translate: {
          y: progressBox.translate.y - 1 // overwrite vertical position to put box in place while height is growing.
      }
    });
  }


  progress.updateRenderGraph();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}

animate();
```

I forked your pen and updated it with the code above. See [Zdog - progress box](https://codepen.io/apappas1129/pen/YzKMaWB)

Note that it seems to be expensive doing the `copy()` method on every animation frame. I am also new to this library and this is currently the fix I know of.